# Flutter Intl - Use of double type in ARB plural translations

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-intl

Been moving over to Flutter 2, and in process moving our translations directly into .arb format, as now [suggested](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). However hitting an issue where the generated l10n translation files can't understand when a type should be `double` and instead uses `int`, which causes type errors when used in code. There doesn't seem to be any way to specify that a particular placeholder substitution would be a `double` rather than an `int`.

**ARB Translations File**

```
"hours": "{hours,plural, =1{Hour}other{Hours}}",
"@hours": {
  "placeholders": {
    "hours": {}
  }
},
```

Tried adding type information to the placeholder, but seems to have little impact on generation (using `flutter gen-l10n` script)

```
"hours": "{hours,plural, =1{Hour}other{Hours}}",
"@hours": {
  "placeholders": {
    "hours": {
      "type: "double" <========== THIS SEEMS TO HAVE NO IMPACT (and/or may not be valid)
    }
  }
},
```

**Generated l10n translations.dart**

```
/// In en, this message translates to:
/// **'{hours,plural, =1{Hour}other{Hours}}'**
String hours(int hours); <========== THIS NEEDS TO BE A DOUBLE
```

**Code usage**

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.hours(1.0)
```

In the previous method of using the Intl library (which is still an option, but the [ARB generation tools](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_translation) are stale and/or multi-staged, and so attempting to move away), this was fairly easy as we controlled the types

```
String HOURS([double hours = 0]) => Intl.plural(
   hours,
   one: 'Hour',
   other: 'Hours',
   name: 'HOURS',
   args: <Object>[hours],
   locale: localeName,
);
```

We could of course have multiple strings in our translations, and manually handle the pluralisation, but given the power of plural in `intl`, it feels like this should be possible? Any advice?

Comment: Why don't just pass the double as a string with the proper formatting?

Comment: @croxx5f I would still need to handle pluralisation myself. Presenting the double isn't so much the issue, it's more how to handle "1.0 hour" vs "2.5 hours"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need a placeholder type to be `double`, you must also add the `format` parameter. Some possible values: "compact", "currency", "decimalPattern" (the most general).

You can find more of them here: https://localizely.com/flutter-arb/

Sample localization:

```
"validation_errors_min_value": "The value must be greater than {min}",
"@validation_errors_min_value": {
    "placeholders": {
        "min": {
            "type": "double",
            "format": "decimalPattern"
        }
    }
}
```